# Confirm Before Deleting with Sweet Alert Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, crud, sweetalert, laravel-5.5

I want the sweet alert box to go out without deleting.

But id not found for ajax

**Route**

```
Route::get('room/delete/{id}', 'RoomList@destroy')->name('roomdelete');
```

**View** File **rooms-list.blade.php**

```
@foreach($rooms as $room)
<tr>
    <td>{!! $room->room_id !!}</td>
    <td>{!! $room->hotel_id !!}</td>
    <td>{!! $room->room_name !!}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="" class="button" data-id="{!! $room->room_id !!}"> <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i> </a></td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

**SweetAlert** Js Code above

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure!",
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
            showCancelButton: true,
        },
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{url('room/delete')}}",
                data: {id:id},
                success: function (data) {

                    }
            });
    });
});


</script>
```

**Controller** File **RoomList.php**

```
public function destroy($id) {

        $rooms = Room::find($id);
        $rooms->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('deleted', 'Delete Success!');

    }
```

Clicking on the delete button does not work

Best Regards

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you have a `GET` route and you are sending a `POST` request here so first change your ajax method to `GET` like this:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure!",
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
            showCancelButton: true,
        },
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{url('room/delete/')}}+id", // since your route has /{id} 
                data: {id:id},
                success: function (data) {

                    }
            });
    });
});


</script>
```

Also I'm not sure about `$(document).on('click', '.button', function (e)` I guess it should be like this:

```
$('.button').on('click', '.button', function (e)
```

Let me know If you still have any issue.